# Длинный MAC адрес

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp

Поставил на Hyper-V виртуальную машину с линукс (Ubuntu 18.04). Выдал ей внешний сетевой интерфейс. И на DHCP сервере жестко сопоставил мак-адрес машины и выдаваемый ip адрес. Машина стабильно получает IP адрес из свободного пула.

При этом в логе DHCP сервера присутствуют два запроса от этой машины

```
Код Дата,Время,Описание,IP-адрес,Имя узла,MAC-адрес
11,01/25/19,14:01:40,Обновить,192.168.1.110,ubuntu,C6180F0E00020000AB1106C5E44DF6D1136D,
11,01/25/19,14:10:54,Обновить,192.168.1.98,ubuntu,00155D840107,
```

(Код события 11 - Аренда продолжена для клиента)

Адрес `00155D840107` соответствует тому мак-адресу, что я вижу в `ifconfig` и который пробит в настройках DHCP сервера. Адрес `C6180F0E00020000AB1106C5E44DF6D1136D` мне неизвестен и уж очень он большой. Но именно по нему машина получает IP адрес 192.168.1.110.

Если выполнить

```
dhclient -r eth0
dhclient eth0
```

То на какое-то время машина начинает отзываться на адрес 192.168.1.98 (хотя ifconfig утверждает, что адрес 192.168.1.110 не поменялся), но потом опять его теряет.

Вот вывод `ifconfig -a`

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe84:107  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:84:01:07  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 36692  bytes 51698054 (51.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 18  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18147  bytes 1363052 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 196  bytes 15474 (15.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 196  bytes 15474 (15.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Вопросы: что это за такой 18-байтовый мак-адрес и как машину посадить на 98 адрес

Comment: а какой DHCP-сервер используешь? «MAC-адресов» таких уж точно быть не может,так что скорей всего это он чудит...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Встроенный в Win2003

Comment: Это клиент айди. Дхчп снупинг и все такое

Comment: [почему ifconfig/route не подходят для диагностики в gnu/linux?](https://unixforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=129712)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin `ip a` выводит информацию аналогичную `ifconfig`

Comment: @eri И что с этим делать?

Comment: мой комментарий в первую очередь относился к этой фразе: «То на какое-то время машина начинает отзываться на адрес 192.168.1.98 (хотя ifconfig утверждает, что адрес 192.168.1.110 не поменялся), но потом опять его теряет.» // ну и вообще — почитайте текст по ссылке. раз вы до сих пор пользуетесь программой ifconfig (которая некорректно работает уже 19 лет) — написанное там вам явно будет полезно.

Comment: а вообще вопрос, конечно, относится к dhcp-серверу, а не к клиенту.

Comment: И к релюшке виндовой виртуалки

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, а если IPv6 отключить, то запись всё равно появляется?